# How do I store binary data from post to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have small images I want to store as a bin data item. The form is posted but I do not know what to do in the controller so that if I so this, the data is stored. I am using Sails.js and the form is passing data as "image" with the form having a file input type.

```
var image = new Images;
image.data = ????
image.save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the images are smaller than 16Mb, you can save them directly using MongoDB's bindata type. You can always convert the binary stream to a Base64 string, and store it as a string file, but that will reduce the allowed image size.

If the image is larger than 16Mb, you have no choice but to use [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is exactly what I want to do. How do I convert the post input to base64 with node?

Comment: You can create a base64 string using a Buffer. Take a look a this article: http://www.hacksparrow.com/base64-encoding-decoding-in-node-js.html

Comment: Can somebody please share any link containing documentation/example of uploading file via bindata type?

Comment: Can you show us how it's done using MongoDB (and without using GridFS)?